# Star notation for Lie group homomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a homomorphism of Lie groups, and $f_*$ is the derivative of $f$ at the identity, what is $f_{*,x}$, for some element $x \in X$? This notation isn't in the book I'm using (Brocker and tom Dieck use $Lf$ instead of $f_*$), but this notation is in a problem set and I'm not sure what it means.

It looks like $f_{*, x}$ is a map from the Lie algebra of $X$ to the Lie algebra of $Y$, so my best guess is that $f_{*, x} = (f \circ l_x)_*$, where $l_x$ is left-translation by $x$.

Comment: Can you include more context? Usually notation like $(f_*)_x$, where $f$ is a smooth map $M \to N$ between smooth manifolds, denotes the differential (derivative) of $f$ at $x$, which is a map $T_x M \to T_{f(x)} N$. Is it possible that $(f_*)_x$ means that in this case, rather than the derivative of $f$ at the identity?

Comment: I think that that is close, but I believe that the differential would be taken at the identity - this because the Lie algebra $LG$ is the fiber of the tangent space at the identity, while the whole tangent space is a simple product $G \times LG$ - I am new to Lie theory but i think it is advantageous to bring points to the identity by translation, and work in $LG$.

Comment: The context to the question is showing that, given the map $f: G \times G \to G \times G$ defined by sending $(x,y) to (x,xy)$, then the map $f_{*,(x,y)}$ is a local bijection for all $(x,y)$

Comment: From that description it really sounds like $f_{*, (x, y)}$ really is supposed to be the tangent map $T_{(x, y)} (G \times G) \to T_{(x, xy)} (G \times G)$ (for a generic point $(x, y)$). Very often when working with Lie groups and algebras it is convenient to translate data to the origin, but I don't think that's what's going on here: Notice that if we take, for example, $x$ to be the identity, the character of $f_{*, (x, e)}$ is special: It is just the identity on $T_{(x, e)} (G \times G) \cong T_x G \oplus LG$, but obviously this identification is exclusive to this case.